# How to make content of a grid scrollable and remove the scrollbar on the right

Tags: html, css

I have a site layout with using CSS grid. I set

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Its a 2x2 grid I want to only the grid iten in the second row to be scrollable depending on their content. I cant get it to work no matter what.

Here is a screenshot of the current situation:

[image]

What I want to achieve in that situation is this:

[image]

Also the item on the right should aswell be scrollable if the content is overflowing the grid item space on the second row. I used `y-overflow:auto` But it only gives me empty scrollbars. Also as extra I want to style the scrollbar, no idea how to do it. Any help is much appreciated.

The html for the site's body is structured as follows:

```
<body class="boundary">
    <div class="body_container">
        <div">...</div>
        <div> ...</div>
        <div>
          <div>MENU</div>
          <div>MENU</div>
          <div>MENU</div>
          ...
        </div>
        <div>TEST</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

The .body_container CSS is:

```
.body_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: replace min-height by height

Comment: omg thank you man :D I was wondering what the issue was all the time and dint see that because I was blind. I would accept it as right answer if you post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `min-height` by `height`